# How do i set Maven to retrieve dependencies first from my own remote repository (Archiva)?

Tags: maven, archiva

How do i set Maven to retrieve external dependencies first from my own remote repository (using Archiva), and if its not found, Archiva will download from external sources, and at the same time saves the downloaded dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have to set up your `.m2/settings.xml` file, nothing fancy. 
[Here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository) is a pretty comprehensive guide. While based on Artifactory, the aspects of POM configuring are obviously general. That should give you all the information you need.